# Netbeans running really really slow on my laptop

Tags: netbeans-7

I am using the OS Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed Netbeans 7.0.1 on it, my laptop's configuration is pretty good but still Netbeans runs really really slow on it and it hangs completely after using it only for a few mins. On doing some research I found that many people suggested to add the following line in the netbeans.conf file "netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64" 
which I did but nothing has changed. It still lags a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of a couple of things I would try. Firstly, upgrade to NetBeans 7.4 as recent versions of NetBeans do more work in background threads, improving the general responsiveness of the application.

Secondly, in the etc directory of the NetBeans install (on Windows) there's a netbeans.conf. Try editing the netbeans_default_options property to set -J-Xmx to something large, maybe 256m or 512m. That should give NB a bit more space to play with.

Comment: Ok, Ill try this and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Upgrading to Netbeans 7.4 helped a lot, there is still a lag and it is nothing compared to 6.9's performance but still quite better than 7.0.1

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if 7.4 is doing a lot more in the background than 6.9 - although I can appreciate that may not be much consolation if it's still slow.

Comment: I just downgraded from 7.4 to 7.3.1 as 7.4 is noticeably slower.

Comment: for syntax `-J-Xmx512m`